# Как получить список свойств телефона?

Tags: android

Где-то давно видел команду консоли (adb shell), по которой можно вывести список свойств, например, имя, брэнд, модель и тп. телефона. Что это за команда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это команда `getprop`

```
adb shell getprop
```

И список свойств:

> `[ro.product.model]: [...]`
> `[ro.product.brand]: [...]`
> `[ro.product.name]: [...]`